# How to tell sublime text not to open two windows

Tags: sublime-text

When I open sublime from a terminal window in the root level of a project

```
$ subl .
```

Two windows open. One is the open to the current working directory (which I want). The Other is a previous session (which I don't want).

Is there a way to curb this behavior? Is there a cache area that I can clear without removing other plugins and settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try disabling the `hot_exit` and `remember_open_files` options in your sublime configuration (*Preferences* → *Settings User*):

```
{
  "hot_exit": false,
  "remember_open_files": false
}
```

---

Source: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=64602

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29236116/755405

Comment: this solution does not work when I use `subl -n`